# Convert bytes data stored in string to bytes again

Tags: python

i have a string storing data of bytes, an example would be instead have b'Hi\x81y' i have an string with 'Hi\x81y'.

So, with the string, how is in utf-8 i can't read the real data..., and i can't found a way to transform the string expression back to the bytes form.

In some way i'm trying to do this:

```
data_str = 'Hi\x81y'
eval("b'{}'".format(data_str))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1
SyntaxError: bytes can only contain ASCII literal characters.
```

Saldy this example don't works and send an error, even worls if we write manually the code .

Any function i test to decode/encode/transform this fails, because python detect the string as utf-8 while is in bytes.

Comment: "_this example don't works and send an error_" If you get an error you should post the logs of it here in the question.

Comment: `eval()` is used in less than <1% of the worlds code *(for a reason)*. If you ever think you need it, what you might want is actually [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) which is half as harmful but does what you probably think `eval()` will solve.

Comment: Hi, i update the post with the error, ast.literal_eval send the same error.

Comment: Include an example of how you set the value of `data_str`; as it is, it's not clear if you have a 4-byte string or a 7-byte string.

Comment: Hi, the example of data_str is in the post..., i'll write in the code only in case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you mean, but you could try any 8 bit encoding.

```
>>> 'Hi\x81y'.encode('latin_1')
b'Hi\x81y'
```

Comment: Nice!, that its. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

To convert bytes into a string, use the `decode` method:

```
mystring = mybytes.decode('utf-8')
```

To convert back the string to bytes, use the `encode` method:

```
mybytes = mystring.encode('utf-8')
```

Comment: Hi, this is not what i'm asking, the problem is when we have sores the data of the bytes in a str, and back from there to bytes.